# Send array with checked Checkbox value and retrieve as string in php

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending checked checkboxes value to php in array.

```
// tag =['Apple','Mango','Tomato']
var tag =  $(this).children().siblings().children().children('input[name="cb"]:checked');
        var tagData = [];
        $.each(tag, function() {
            tagData.push($(this).val());
        });

        console.log(tagData);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {tag: tagData }, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

Console.log data

```
(2) ["Apple", "Apple"]
0: "Apple"
1: "Apple"
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

I'm getting this array in php like this.

```
 $list = $_POST['tag'];
 $imgTag = implode( ", ",$list);
 // i want like this - $imgTag = "Apple,Mango,Tomato".
```

But i getting empty line in php.

Comment: What is the value in `tagData` variable in JS?

Comment: like this - ['Apple','Mango','Tomato']

Comment: And what is the value of $list in php?

Comment: Print `$_POST` to check whether any data posted or not?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh $list echo "[object Object]" and i'm sending many variable and all getting posted.

Comment: Use `print_r($_POST)` to print data not `echo`.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh it printing [tag] => Apple,Tomato

Comment: That's it what you want. Access it as `$_POST['tag']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize your tagData using `JSON.stringify` while sending in ajax request. like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {tag: JSON.stringify(tagData) }, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```